# CSS gradient not applied correctly in html5 website

Tags: html, css

I'm using following website (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate a CSS gradient for the background of my website. In my main CSS file, I put the code like below:

```
body {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f77624+0,f9c655+100 */
    background: #f77624; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f77624 0%, #f9c655 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f77624 0%,#f9c655 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f77624 0%,#f9c655 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f77624', endColorstr='#f9c655',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

When I refresh `index.html` file, I only see the `background color` without the gradient. Is there any error in the CSS code above? If it is any help, I am also using the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/).

Comment: Try clearing the cache on your website using the `F5`, and see if that helps. If not, maybe try adding a runnable code snippet of the website for us, as to debug it.

Comment: Which browser and which version of it you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css gradient code will work only at latest browser.. will not work less than IE9,  NO issue with above code..  just clear the history of browser ..

```css
body {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f77624+0,f9c655+100 */
    background: #f77624; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f77624 0%, #f9c655 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f77624 0%,#f9c655 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f77624 0%,#f9c655 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f77624', endColorstr='#f9c655',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.wrapper {
  width: 95vw;
  height: calc(95vw * 9/16);
  max-height: 95vh;
  max-width: calc(95vh * 16/9);
  background: center;
  background-size:contain;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#lorem {
  color: aqua;
  font-size:10vmin;
 text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p id="lorem">
    This text should scale with div only.
  </p>
</div>
```

created sample : https://jsfiddle.net/70fq44sv/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is *for reference only.*

it's **possible** to use [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) for gradient backgrounds. **it's supported by all modern browsers.**

You can view the source of an SVG background to see how it's structured in this [live example](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3469/no-dimensions-or-ratio.svg) created by MDN

*They scale well and eliminate the need for browser prefixes.*

in the example below I created an SVG and then encoded it into base64 to eliminate the additonal`http request`

```css
.cooldiv {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZyIgeDE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iMTAwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+PHN0b3Agc3R5bGU9InN0b3AtY29sb3I6IHJnYigyMjEsMTUwLDg2KTsiIG9mZnNldD0iMCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0eWxlPSJzdG9wLWNvbG9yOiByZ2IoNTIsMTI3LDE0OSk7IiBvZmZzZXQ9IjEiLz48L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PjxyZWN0IHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiB1cmwoI2cpOyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="cooldiv"></div>
```